# Apex Test Class assertion fails on mismatched strings

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, validation

Actual Class:

```
trigger AvoidDeleteRequirementRecordWhenStatusIsApproved on Requirement__c (before delete) {
    for(Requirement__c r : trigger.old){
        if(r.Status__c == 'Approved'){
            trigger.oldMap.get(r.Id).addError('Cannot Delete Requirement Record Because Requirement Status is Approved ');
        }
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest(seeAllData=false)
public class RequirementNotDelete {
    public static testmethod void donotdelete(){
        Client__c cli = new Client__c();
        cli.Name = 'Test Client';
        insert cli;
        
        Project__c pro = new Project__c(Name='Test project');
        pro.Client__c = cli.Id;
        insert pro;
        
        Requirement__c r = new Requirement__c();
        r.Name = 'Task2';
        r.Project__c = pro.Id;
        r.Status__c= 'Approved';
        insert r;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        Database.DeleteResult result = Database.delete(r, false);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        System.assert(!result.isSuccess());
        System.assert(result.getErrors().size() > 0);
        System.assertEquals('Cannot Delete Requirement Record Because Requirement Status is 
        Approved.',result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
        
    }
}
```

My test fails with the message:

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Cannot Delete Requirement Record Because Requirement Status is Approved, Actual: Cannot Delete Requirement Record Because Requirement Status is Approved

Answer (score 1):

You should generally not assert on the error message copy, but simply whether or not the proper type of error is hit. That said, if you are determined to verify the message, this failure is a great example of why you should define `String` values as *constants* rather than just define them in place wherever you use them. We call the latter pattern "magic strings" and they are a code smell.

Note that in order to even define a constant, you need to move the logic out of your trigger body and into an `Apex Class`, which is pretty much the bare minimum to meet industry-wide best practice.

```
public with sharing class MyObjectValidations
{
    public static final String MY_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Some message';
    public static void preventApproval(List<MyObject__c> records)
    {
        for (MyObject__c record : records)
        {
            if (/*some condition*/)
            {
                record.addError(MY_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you should reference the same variable. Doing so makes it impossible to introduce copy differences between the two strings.

```
system.assertEquals(MyObjectValidations.MY_ERROR_MESSAGE, result.getErrors()[0].getMessage(),
    'You should include assertion messages');
```

The ultimate difference between your two strings should be moot, but one terminates with a period character (`.`), while the other ends in a trailing space.